# Is it possible to have a single XSD with multiple namespaces?

Tags: xml, xsd, namespaces

I know it would be bad practice, but is there a way of combining separate XSDs into a single file, but maintaining the differing namespaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you have to organise a schema so that different target namespaces go in different schema documents.

You could of course maintain the data in some other form and generate the XSD documents, but that doesn't seem very convenient.

Comment: Thanks Michael. Hopefully won't have to go down the latter route.